# Perl parse every number between two values

Tags: regex, perl

say I have a string like:

> blah blah 32.22200119 blah 33.440049 blah blah 32.25009912 7621.22 blah blah 37

I know that the numbers I want to parse are restricted between 32 and 35, and have at least 4 decimal points. How would I go about parsing out just these long numbers, while ignoring all the other numbers? (The numbers I am attempting to parse happen to be longitudinal coordinates)

Comment: For instance, pull all numbers first, then parse one at a time.  _Please_ show your code so that there is a legitimate question.

Comment: `(?<!\S)(?:[-+]?(180(\.0{1,15})?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d{1,15})?)|[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d{1,15})?|90(\.0{1,15})?))(?!\S)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something along the lines of...

```
while ($line =~ /\b(3[2-5]\.\d{4,})\b/g)
{
    print "Found $1\n";
}
```

That's for a single line. You'll have to loop over multiple lines if needed.